# Compile issue when upgrading Platform Toolset from v120 to v142 (visualstudio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a project I can compile in VS2019 without issue using platform toolset v120.
I retargeted the project to use platform toolset v142 and WSDK 10.  I get the following compile errors related to templates.  Any thoughts on what is causes this?

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
 Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\utility(573,1): error
 C2440: '=': cannot convert from '_Other' to '_Ty'

```
        with
        [
            _Other=int
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=std::_Container_proxy *
        ] (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\utility(573,42): message : Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\deque(872): message : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty *std::exchange<std::_Container_proxy*,int>(_Ty &,_Other &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::_Container_proxy *,
            _Other=int
        ] (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\deque(869): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::deque<T,std::allocator<T>>::~deque(void) noexcept'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ] (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)
D:\dev\_inc\lockqueue.h(46): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::deque<T,std::allocator<T>>::~deque(void) noexcept' being compiled
        with
        [
           T=int
        ] (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)
D:\dev\_inc\lockqueue.h(109): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::deque<T,std::allocator<T>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ] (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)
D:\dev\_inc\lockqueue.h(116): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'CLockQueueTX<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ] (compiling source file RTPPacketSequencer.cpp)'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You possibly have some code somewhere redefining a macro that's internally used by MSVC headers.

I had a similar problem on a project where I was trying to provide a `#define nullptr 0` compat macro in my own headers, when run in C++98/C++03 mode. Making sure that I wasn't defining this on `_MSC_VER` environnements solved the issue.